# SSRS Client Licensing in desktop application

Tags: reporting-services, licensing, reportviewer

Is there a licensing requirement for the SSRS client in a desktop application? The application will be pulling the reporting information from either SQL CE or flat files.

I assume that since the report viewer is built into .NET that, like every other .NET control, there would not be an additional licensing cost.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The ReportViewer control is a component of Visual Studio and is freely distributable with your applications.

Report Server, however, is subject to the normal SQL Server licensing.

The specific difference is running the report in local or remote processing mode.

Sources:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a941c6b2-64dd-4d03-9ca7-4017a0d164fd&displaylang=en

http://www.gotreportviewer.com/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Great answer pulled from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067.aspx which indicates that client processing of RDLC files is free from licensing.

The ReportViewer control supports a local processing mode that allows you to run client report definition (.rdlc) files using the built-in processing capability of the control. The client reports that you run in local processing mode can be easily created in your application project. There are four [sic] approaches to creating the report:

-Create a new client report definition (.rdlc) file using the Report Wizard.

-Create a new client report definition (.rdlc) file in Visual Studio.

-Generate a report definition programmatically.